Flutter format currency from Currency Code
I am already saving the currencyCode for my users but formatting actual price-Strings is not 100% correct.
This is my code:
   String toFormattedPrice(BuildContext context) {
    return NumberFormat.currency(
      symbol: CurrencyService2.getCurrencySymbolFromCode(
        Provider.of<CurrencyProvider>(context).currentCurrencyCode,
      ),
      locale: Provider.of<LocaleProvider>(context).currentLocale.languageCode,
    ).format(this);
   }

But the problem is locale:. Because it messes up the digits. But how can I get this correct?
I am saving this model has currency (using currency picker ) :
class Currency {
  ///The currency code
  final String code;

  ///The currency name in English
  final String name;

  ///The currency symbol
  final String symbol;

  ///The currency flag code
  ///
  /// To get flag unicode(Emoji) use [CurrencyUtils.currencyToEmoji]
  final String? flag;

  ///The currency number
  final int number;

  ///The currency decimal digits
  final int decimalDigits;

  ///The currency plural name in English
  final String namePlural;

  ///The decimal separator
  final String decimalSeparator;

  ///The thousands separator
  final String thousandsSeparator;

  ///True if symbol is on the Left of the amount
  final bool symbolOnLeft;

  ///True if symbol has space with amount
  final bool spaceBetweenAmountAndSymbol;

  bool get isFlagImage => flag?.endsWith('.png') ?? false;

      Currency({
        required this.code,
        required this.name,
        required this.symbol,
        required this.flag,
        required this.number,
        required this.decimalDigits,
        required this.namePlural,
        required this.symbolOnLeft,
        required this.decimalSeparator,
        required this.thousandsSeparator,
        required this.spaceBetweenAmountAndSymbol,
      });
    
      Currency.from({required Map<String, dynamic> json})
          : code = json['code'],
            name = json['name'],
            symbol = json['symbol'],
            number = json['number'],
            flag = json['flag'],
            decimalDigits = json['decimal_digits'],
            namePlural = json['name_plural'],
            symbolOnLeft = json['symbol_on_left'],
            decimalSeparator = json['decimal_separator'],
            thousandsSeparator = json['thousands_separator'],
            spaceBetweenAmountAndSymbol = json['space_between_amount_and_symbol'];
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
            'code': code,
            'name': name,
            'symbol': symbol,
            'number': number,
            'flag': flag,
            'decimal_digits': decimalDigits,
            'name_plural': namePlural,
            'symbol_on_left': symbolOnLeft,
            'decimal_separator': decimalSeparator,
            'thousands_separator': thousandsSeparator,
            'space_between_amount_and_symbol': spaceBetweenAmountAndSymbol,
          };
    }


Use intl package.
String formatCurrency(double amount, String currencyCode) {
  NumberFormat formatCurrency = NumberFormat.currency(locale: 'en_${currencyCode}');
  return formatCurrency.format(amount);
}

